# Enque Typekit Fonts - Not Found

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to enqueue a typekit on my WP site in a function using code below:

```
/**
 * TypeKit Fonts
 *
 * @since Theme 1.0
 */
function theme_typekit() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_typekit', '//use.typekit.net/xxxxxxx.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_typekit' );

function theme_typekit_inline() {
  if ( wp_script_is( 'theme_typekit', 'done' ) ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<?php }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_typekit_inline' );
```

Code appears to be working fine, however when url called on frontend it's showing 404 in console for link, `https://use.typekit.net/xxxxxxx.js`

Any idea why not found? Note, I'm using a valid typekit code on my end.

Comment: Looks good to me. Did you publish your font kit? Can you browse the file: `https://use.typekit.net/xxxxxxx.js`?

Comment: Yup...exactly the issue. I didn't publish, duh! It's working fine now. Thanks for response.

Comment: Glad I could help :) 
I also added my comment as an answer so you can mark this question as solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code snippet is working fine. Nevertheless the font kit has to be published within the *Kit Editor*:

1. Login to your Typekit account
2. Locate the *Kit Editor* (see: https://typekit.com/kit_editor/kits/xxxxxxx)
3. Click the *Publish* button (bottom right)

You may also consider using the new embed code provided by Typekit:

```
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
```